# Converting dataframe to dictionary with key and multiple value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an usecase where I have to read xl file with multiple header columns and values.

```
I have to convert that into a dictionary, key with multiple values.
The xl header will vary each time, some times 2 columns some to three, and so on.

The sample data frame for an xl file is
      key1    key2
      abc     xyz
      bca     yxz
      cab     zxy

the output should be as...
   {'key1': ['abc','bca','cab'], 'key2': ['xyz','yxz', 'zxy']}

if there is one more column key3, I should able to include that as well in the dictionary
```

.

```
import pandas as pd
workbook_loc = "c:\\2020\Book1.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(workbook_loc, sheet_name=None)
data_dict = df.to_dict()

but the above script is throwing out  AttributeErro 'dict' object has no attribute.

what is the wrong I am doing?
```

Comment: `sheet_name=None` returns a ordered dictionary and not a dataframe, you need to either concat the values of the dictionary or select the specific key for which you want the value

Comment: I can't use group by on specific column, the columns(headers) will vary each time, need to write generic code.

Comment: okay, after using anky's suggestion try `df.stack().groupby(level=1).agg(list).to_dict()`

Comment: @Datanovice, I tried your suggestion, getting 
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'stack'

Comment: because you didn't concat the dataframe, `df  = pd.concat(df)`

Comment: @Datanovice, you mean to say, 1st do concatenation and then create a dictionary?
df =pd.concat(df)

df.stack().groupby(level=1).agg(list).to_dict()

Comment: Yep that's right my dude, I'm sure the wording is clear

Comment: @Datanovice, I tired but while creating the dictionary, on the suggested line throwing out error  TypeError: Must provide 'func' or named aggregation **kwargs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify *sheet_name=None* it returns a dictionary instead of pandas dataframe. its always good practice to specify a sheet name.

You can try this..

```
import pandas as pd
workbook_loc = "c:\\2020\Book1.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(workbook_loc, index_col=0, sheet_name='Sheet1')
data_dict = {}
for col in df.columns:
    data_dict[col]=[row for row in df[col]]
```

Comment: the code is giving, second key and its values in the form dictionary, but missing out 1stkey from data frame...

{'key2': ['xyz','yxz', 'zxy']}

missing out 1st key(key1 and its values)

Comment: samata, the solution is coorect, with small change, the index_col, trying to set 1st column is index is no longer a value, just removing index_col will work fine...

import pandas as pd
workbook_loc = "c:\\2020\Book1.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(workbook_loc,sheet_name='Sheet1')
data_dict = {}
for col in df.columns:
    data_dict[col]=[row for row in df[col]]